# LINQ Queries with dynamic Order By

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I have a query where I need to have ordeby based on a querystring parameter .For example if sortby parameter is price , Query needs to change with price . If its rating than change query to sort by rating .

I know PredicateBuilder can do And and OR stuff but how do I make a dynamic ordeby linq query .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you could use a switch statement or something similar:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = ...;

switch (orderByParameter)
{
    case "price":
        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Price);
        break;
    case "rating":
        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Rating);
        break;
    // etc
}
```

You could also do it with reflection, but assuming you have a limited number of fields to order by, this is quite possibly the simplest approach.

Answer (score 22):

If you know exactly which are all the posible parameters that can be used to order, the Jon´s answer is the best one. But if you have an unknown number of parameters you can build the expression dynamically. e.g:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var people = new[]{
            new Person { Name = "David", Age = 40 },
            new Person { Name = "Maria", Age = 12 },
            new Person { Name = "Lucas", Age = 45 }
        }.AsQueryable();

        foreach (var p in people.OrderBy("Age"))
        {
            Console.Write(p.Name);
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}

static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string propertyName)
    {
        var typeOfT = typeof(T);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeOfT, "parameter");
        var propertyType = typeOfT.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
        var propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
        var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

        var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { typeOfT, propertyType }, items.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderExpression));
        return items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @lontivero answer.

If you want to do dynamic sorting of multiple items both ascending and descending you can do something similar to this below.  Adds the OrderByDescending, ThenBy, ThenByDescending methods

```
static class IQueryableExtensions
 {
     public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string propertyName)
     {
         var typeOfT = typeof(T);
         var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeOfT, "parameter");
         var propertyType = typeOfT.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
         var propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
         var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

         var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { typeOfT, propertyType }, items.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderExpression));
         return items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
     }

     public static IQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string propertyName)
     {
         var typeOfT = typeof(T);
         var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeOfT, "parameter");
         var propertyType = typeOfT.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
         var propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
         var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

         var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { typeOfT, propertyType }, items.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderExpression));
         return items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
     }

     public static IQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string propertyName)
     {
         var typeOfT = typeof(T);
         var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeOfT, "parameter");
         var propertyType = typeOfT.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
         var propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
         var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

         var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "ThenBy", new Type[] { typeOfT, propertyType }, items.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderExpression));
         return items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
     }

     public static IQueryable<T> ThenByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string propertyName)
     {
         var typeOfT = typeof(T);
         var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeOfT, "parameter");
         var propertyType = typeOfT.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
         var propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
         var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

         var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "ThenByDescending", new Type[] { typeOfT, propertyType }, items.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderExpression));
         return items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
     }
 }
```