# Switch variable to use externally

Tags: c#

### The goal

Declare some variable within a `switch` and use it externally.

### The problem

I  don't know the syntax.

### What I'm thought about

To perform my problem, I was thinking to do something like this, but doesn't work because it is just a philosophy:

```
public ActionResult Compare(int id, string orderBy)
{
    var productsList = Products.BuildIndividualProductComparisonList(id);
    var product = Products.BuildToCompare(id);


        switch (orderBy)
        {
            case "lowestToBiggest":
                var organizedProductsList = 
                    productsList.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
                break;
            case "biggestToLowest":
                var organizedProductsList = 
                    productsList.OrderBy(x => x.maxProductPrice);
                break;
            default:
                var organizedProductsList = 
                    productsList.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
                break;
        }

    ComparisonViewModel comparisonViewModel =
        new ComparisonViewModel
        {
            Product = product,
            ProductList = organizedProductsList
        };

    return View(comparisonViewModel);
}
```

### Spotlight

This is my original C#'s code that works good:

```
public ActionResult Compare(int id, string orderBy)
{
    var productsList = Products.BuildIndividualProductComparisonList(id);
    var product = Products.BuildToCompare(id);

    ComparisonViewModel comparisonViewModel =
        new ComparisonViewModel
        {
            Product = product,
            ProductList = productsList
        };

    return View(comparisonViewModel);
}
```

### The question

Someone has any idea to resolve my problem?

Comment: You need to declare a variable of the appropriate type *outside* the scope of your switch statements, then assign to it in your switch

Comment: might i recommend adding `switch (orderBy.ToUpper())` and using all uppercase in your `case` statements, to ensure character casing is not an issue

Comment: Just a suggestion, but couldn't you create a variable out of the Switch{} scope? Check what the type of organizedProductsList is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare variable outside switch block and assign value to it. Also try not to use `List` suffix for collection names:

```
IEnumerable<Product> sortedProducts;

switch (orderBy)
{
    case "lowestToBiggest":
        sortedProducts = products.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
        break;
    case "biggestToLowest":
        sortedProducts = products.OrderBy(x => x.maxProductPrice);
        break;
    default:
        sortedProducts = products.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
        break;
}
```

Actually your code can be simplified to:

```
IEnumerable<Product> sortedProducts =
   products.OrderBy(p => orderBy == "biggestToLowest" ?
                         p.maxProductPrice : 
                         p.minProductPrice);
```

Comment: Your ternary will be deprecated when there are more than two cases. Any idea?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge it depends.. you want sorting to occur on database server or on client side? About deprecated ternary.. I program to YAGNI, and currently switch block looks deprecated :)

Comment: `orderBy` comes from a URL parameter — I want to sort to display to client.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge I mean products are `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`(i.e. `List<T>`)?

Comment: Oh, sorry! `IEnumerable` =)

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge sorry, was afk. If you need to provide ordering by many different fields, then you have several options - simple switch as above, [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), or [building expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856060/linq-queries-with-dynamic-order-by) which sorts by property name. I'd go with simple switch, but extracted to separate method `GetProductsOrderdBy(string orderBy` to make your main method cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

> Declare some variable within a switch and use it externally.

You **can't**. Variables defined inside the scope would only be visible within that scope.

You have to declare your variable outside the `switch` statement and then you will be able to use it outside.

I see that you are using `var` (Implicitly typed variable) and you can't declare it outside of your `switch` statement, *(since that needs to be assigned)*, You should see: [Declaring an implicitly typed variable inside conditional scope and using it outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751507/declaring-an-implicitly-typed-variable-inside-conditional-scope-and-using-it-out) and the [answer from Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751779/961113)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the declaration of the variable outside of the `switch` block.
You have to specify the type of the variable at declaration, though, instead of using `var` because the type cannot be inferred.

```
public ActionResult Compare(int id, string orderBy)
{
    var productsList = Products.BuildIndividualProductComparisonList(id);
    var product = Products.BuildToCompare(id);
    var organizedProductsList = null;


        switch (orderBy)
        {
            case "lowestToBiggest":
                organizedProductsList = 
                    productsList.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
                break;
            case "biggestToLowest":
                organizedProductsList = 
                    productsList.OrderBy(x => x.maxProductPrice);
                break;
            default:
                organizedProductsList = 
                    productsList.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
                break;
        }

    ComparisonViewModel comparisonViewModel =
        new ComparisonViewModel
        {
            Product = product,
            ProductList = organizedProductsList
        };

    return View(comparisonViewModel);
}
```

Comment: If you strongly type the organizedProductsList, should work - but not using 'var'.

Comment: @BrokenGlass you're right, i was a little too enthusiastic in posting an answer, as other users are always so freaking fast.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a variable outside its enclosing scope.

Either:

1. Move the variable to a wider scope. The downside of this is that we always strive to keep scope as narrow as possible.
2. Extract the switch statement into a function and have it return the value.

Option 1 is, I think, obvious. To expand on option 2, the code would look like this:

```
ProductList organizedProductsList(...)
{
    return productsList.OrderBy(...);
}

....

ComparisonViewModel comparisonViewModel =
    new ComparisonViewModel
    {
        Product = product,
        ProductList = organizedProductsList(...)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need declare the variable **organizedProductsList** outside your case statement, as it will only have scope with the case statement.

Note: I can't tell what Products.BuildIndividualProductComparisonList(id) returns, I presume its a List of Products.

Thus something like:

```
IEnumerable<Products> organizedProductsList = null;
switch (orderBy)
    {
        case "lowestToBiggest":
            organizedProductsList = 
                productsList.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
            break;
        case "biggestToLowest":
            organizedProductsList = 
                productsList.OrderBy(x => x.maxProductPrice);
            break;
        default:
            organizedProductsList = 
                productsList.OrderBy(x => x.minProductPrice);
            break;
    }
```